# Equivalent of jQuery's wrapInner() in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and while I'm trying to do everything the angular way,  I need to wrap all `<li>` elements with a `<span>`.  Many of these `<li>` elements will be received from different `http` requests. So I need to dynamically wrap all `<li>` elements with a `<span>`.

```
<li><span class="item-content">Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
```

I know I can achieve this with to use  [jQuery .wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/).  But is it possible with AngularJS?  Can AngularJS search the DOM and update content like this? How can I use jQuery with AngularJS?

### UPDATE

Following on from @devqon answer, I've added this code snippet.

**wrap all li elements in a specific html scope**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
   $scope.test = "controller is working if you can see this";
  });
  app.directive("wrapInner", function () {
   return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element) {
              // Note that this will only fire once, and won't work with dynamically added li elements
              element.find("li").wrapInner('<span class="item-content"></span>');
          }
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
 {{test}}
 <ul wrapp-inner>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque vitae, recusandae, error expedita ea voluptatem!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur est esse quos dolorem amet quam, nisi sed voluptatem unde! Fuga iusto labore, porro nemo, nam quo dolore ullam atque quidem.</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

**wrap all li elements in your application**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
   $scope.test = "controller is working if you can see this";
  });
  // By naming the directive 'li' and restrict to 'E' (element), angular will
  // apply it to all <li> elements
  app.directive("li", function () {
   return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, element) {
     element.wrapInner('<span class="item-content"></span>');
    }
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
 {{test}}
 <ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque vitae, recusandae, error expedita ea voluptatem!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur est esse quos dolorem amet quam, nisi sed voluptatem unde! Fuga iusto labore, porro nemo, nam quo dolore ullam atque quidem.</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: if your doing dom manipulation then you are not using angular for what is build for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive for this:

```
app.directive("wrapInner", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.wrapInner("<span></span>");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<li wrap-inner>Lorem Ipsum</li>
```

Which will result in the following html:

```
<li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to inner wrap **all** `li` elements in a specific html scope, you can do something like this:

```
app.directive("wrapInner", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            // Note that this will only fire once, and won't work with dynamically added li elements
            element.find("li").wrapInner("<span></span>");
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div wrapp-inner>
    <!-- a lot of li's -->
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwjuspbL/1/

Or, if you want to wrap **all** `li` elements in your application, just write a directive for `li`:

```
// By naming the directive 'li' and restrict to 'E' (element), angular will
// apply it to all <li> elements
app.directive("li", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.wrapInner("<span></span>");
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwjuspbL/

Comment: Your answer fits well his needs, but I think we should rather explain him why editing the DOM this way is not *the Angular way*. +1 anyway

Comment: @devqon, that's useful to know but I won't be producing the HTML for this, it's coming from a CMS API so I won't be able to add the `wrap-inner` part to the HTML

Comment: @devqon, I tried both those methods and neither worked, I added a code snippet to my question to demonstrated.  It's giving the error `TypeError: element.wrapInner is not a function`

Comment: Have you included jquery.js? `wrapInner` is not a jq-light function (which is default used by angular), so you have to include jquery (which then will be used by angular)

Comment: @Holy, Try with `$(element).wrapInner()`

Comment: @devqon, thanks after adding jquery it worked for the second solution, but not for the first?  Did I add jquery the correct way?